# Spark Streaming Create Multiple RDD/DataFrame from DStream by Unique ID

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql, rdd

A couple of questions:

1) What would be the best way to create multiple RDDs/DataFrames from an existing RDD by unique ID?

2) Can this be done on the DStream level?

I want to be able to create a different set of RDDs/Dataframes based on a project ID from an existing RDD. The main RDD will contain different data, something like so:

```
{"ApplicationVersion":"1.0.3 (65)","ProjectId":30024,"TargetId":"4138","Timestamp":"2017-06-29T09:25:46.0791317Z"}

{"ApplicationVersion":"1.0.3 (65)","ProjectId":30025,"TargetId":"4138","Timestamp":"2017-06-29T09:25:46.0791317Z","ProjectId30025Field":"SomeValue"}

{"ApplicationVersion":"1.0.3 (65)","ProjectId":30026,"TargetId":"4138","Timestamp":"2017-06-29T09:25:46.0791317Z","ProjectId30026Field":"SomeValue"}
```

- Some fields are common but there will be additional/different fields
  depending on the projectID i.e. projectId 30024 might have two more
  fields vs projectId 30025.
- Also, only the common fields would be known upfront, the other fields
  unique per projectId are dynamic.
- ProjectIDs will not be known upfront as well

From a DStream, I loop over RDDs:

```
val kinesisStream = KinesisUtils.createStream(
     ssc, appName, "Kinesis_Stream", "kinesis.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com",
     "region", InitialPositionInStream.LATEST, kinesisCheckpointInterval, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2)

     val lines = kinesisStream.map(x => new String(x))

     lines.foreachRDD((rdd, time) =>{

       val sqlContext = SQLContextSingleton.getInstance(rdd.sparkContext)

       if(rdd.count() > 0){
        //Can I create multiple RDDs/DataFrame here?
        //dataFrameforProjId30024
        //dataFrameforProjId30025
        //dataFrameforProjId30026
       }
     })
```

The reason I want to separate by projectIds is because when I create a DataFrame, I want the schema to be specific to the projectId, also I want to be able to export the data separately by projectId as well later.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: //Can I create multiple RDDs/DataFrame here? -> Yes you can.

Comment: Are the ProjectId":xxxxx known beforehand?

Comment: nope, they will not be known beforehand

Comment: You can apply a filter and based on the filter route your data into set of rdd to convert into dataframe for applying schema.